# Add string to regex pattern in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern in js, and it works fine but I want to alternatively add or to match a string "jjjj". Basically, it has to match the pattern or this string must be entered to pass by. 
Working pattern:

```
[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}
```

What I was expecting:

```
[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2} | (jjjj)
```

Comment: Remove the spaces around `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is your enemy here. `) | (` should be `)|(`.

`([A-Z])\w+[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}|(jjjj)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces around the `|`. This would work:

`[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}|jjj`

You can test this here: https://regex101.com/

## Regular Expression

`[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}|jjj`

## Test String

```
a00 0AA
jjj
```

Comment: cheer for more details and the link!